# How to combine multiple formatters?

Tags: sapui5

I made a generic function that generates some form fields, because I need them at many different places in my app.
It has an optional parameter for setting the visibility of the fields.

But now I need to add additional visibility rules for specific fields.
These additional rules should stay the same for all function calls, so theoretically there's no need to set them through a new parameter.
Unfortunately these specific rules are overwritten if the visibility parameter is set.
My goal is to extend these rules with the visibility parameter.

Here's a minimal example:
The specific visibility rule is that an input's value has to be greater than 0.
On one function call another visibility rule is that the value of `FlagSet` need to be equal to `"yes"`.

```js
let data = {
  "FlagSet": "yes",
  "Data": [{
      "Size": 1
    },
    {
      "Size": 0
    }
  ]
};

let oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(data);

let oPage = new sap.m.VBox();
oPage.setModel(oModel);

let additionalVisibilityRules = [
  false,
  {
    path: "/FlagSet",
    formatter: (flagSet) => (flagSet === "yes")
  }
];

for (let i = 0, l = data.Data.length; i < l; i++)
  oPage.addItem(getFields(i, additionalVisibilityRules[i]));

function getFields(index, oVisibility) {
  let oCtrl = new sap.m.Input({
    value: `{/Data/${index}/Size}`
  }).bindProperty("visible", {
    path: `/Data/${index}/Size`,
    formatter: (size) => (size > 0)
  });

  if (oVisibility) {
    oCtrl.bindProperty("visible", oVisibility);
  }

  return oCtrl;
}

oPage.placeAt("content");
```

```html
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

How can I combine it so that the second input field is only visible if both its value is above 0 AND `FlagSet` is equal to `"yes"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple model properties, you could try using **Composite Binding**

Here is an example from the documentation:

```xml
<TextField value="{
    parts: [
        {path:'birthday/day'},
        {path:'birthday/month'},
        {path:'birthday/year'}
    ], 
    formatter:'my.globalFormatter'}"/>
```

For more information see:
https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/e2e6f4127fe4450ab3cf1339c42ee832